# Does @isTest(OnInstall=False) have any effect on unpackaged code?

Tags: deployment, unit-test

I am wondering if using this attribute will keep my test from running when I push code from sandbox to production?

Specifically I would like to use this to create bulk tests that I may not want to run when I push code to production (in order to keep deployment quick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this does not apply to unpackaged code, as per the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) this is for package installs only. So if your using Eclipse, Changesets or Migration Toolkit (aka Metadata API) the platform will run all tests included and insist on the required 75%+ coverage.

> Use the IsTest(OnInstall=true) annotation to specify which Apex tests are executed during package installation. This annotation is used for tests in managed or unmanaged packages. Only test methods with this annotation, or methods that are part of a test class that has this annotation, will be executed during package installation. Tests annotated to run during package installation must pass in order for the package installation to succeed.

One option is to use UserInfo.getOrganizationId to check if the test is running in your production org and simply return from it. The test will still pass and execute quickly. So long as not running these tests does not result in reduced code coverage this admmittly rather crude check should work for you.

Comment: Yea, the pattern I'm using runs the test as a singular and then runs it in bulk so the code coverage wouldn't change. This would keep me from executing the test manually on production tho.